# How do I fix this invalid type error in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an Error in Docker Compose. it says :

ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array

Here's my docker-compose.yml

Thank you for your help!

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: nodejs 
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env 
    environment: 
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=db
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB
    ports: 
      - "8080:8000"
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes: 
      - .:/home/node/app
      - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ./wait-for.sh db:27017 -- /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js

  db:
    image: mongo 
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      -"27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Comment: Under `db: { ports: }`, you're missing a space in between `-` and `"27018:..."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems you have several issues in that Compose File:

**#1 Invalid Type**

> services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array

The fix is just an space at the port:

```
    ports:
      -"27018:27017"  # OLD
      - "27018:27017" # NEW
```

**#2 Typos with Names**

> Service 'app' has a link to service 'mongo' which is undefined.

Link it to `db` instead `mongo` like this:

```
    links:
      - mongo # OLD (mongo doesn't exist)
      - db    # New
```

**#3 Volumes not defined:**

> Named volume "dbdata:/data/db:rw" is used in service "db" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

or

> ERROR: Named volume "node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules:rw" is used in service "app" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

You need to define the Volume section, something like this:

```
volumes:
  dbdata: {}
  node_modules: {}
```

**#3 Undefined Network:**

> Service "db" uses an undefined network "app-network"

Which needs the definition of the custom networks you intend to create, something like this:

```
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: custom-driver-1
```

Documentation for Docker Compose is really straight forward, in case you haven't taken a look:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/

And whenever you get an error... just look for the typo and run it again...  this is what I did:

```
~ > ls
docker-compose.yml
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
WARNING: The MONGO_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MONGO_DB variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
~ > export MONGO_PORT=hello
~ > export MONGO_DB=world
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
ERROR: Service 'app' has a link to service 'mongo' which is undefined.
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: ~/.env
~ > touch .env
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
ERROR: Named volume "dbdata:/data/db:rw" is used in service "db" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
ERROR: Named volume "node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules:rw" is used in service "app" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
ERROR: Service "db" uses an undefined network "app-network"
~ > docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
db uses an image, skipping
app uses an image, skipping
```